# PageView indicator dots not working in Persistent Bottomsheet Flutter

Tags: flutter, pageviews

I am creating a PageView with dots indicator in Persistent bottom sheet.
The bottom sheet appears with page views and dot indicator. But when I horizontally scroll it has no effect in dots view.

My code hierarchy goes as below:

```
class zzz extends StatefulWidget with ccc {
  @override
  State createState() => new xxxState();
}

class xxxState extends State< zzz > with qqq {
    ..
    ...
    Stack(
      pageview(
        onPageChanged: (index) {
              setState(() {
                      this.bottomSheetCurrentIndex = index;
              });
            },
      )

      dotsView()
    )
```

Dots view below :

```
 Widget dotsview(double pages) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: 40,
        child: ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 180),
            itemCount: pages.toInt(),
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Container(
                height: 10,
                width: 10,
                child: dotcontainer(pages, index),
              );
            }
        )
    );
  }

  //indicator style
  Container dotcontainer(double pages, int index) {
        return Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 2.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              color: this.bottomSheetCurrentIndex == index
                  ? Colors.blue
                  : Colors.grey),
        );
  }
```

Why? Any solution for this ?

Answer (score 2):

As usual, most of my questions never get answers from this platform.
Any ways, the answer to above problem is using `Scopped Model or Inherited widgets.`

Thanks